# Prolog single-variable query returns an error. Why?

Tags: prolog

I've created a simple Prolog program (using GNU Prolog v1.4.4) with a single fact:

```
sunny.
```

When I run the following query:

```
sunny.
```

I get:

```
yes
```

As I'd expect.  When I run this query:

```
X.
```

I get:

```
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,top_level/0)
```

when I expected to get:

```
X = sunny
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prolog is based on first-order logic but `X` is a second order logic query (the variable stands for a rule head / fact, not only a term): you ask "which predicates can be derived?" or in other words "which formulas are true?". Second order logic is so expressive that we lose many nice properties of first-order logic (*). That's why a second order variable must be sufficiently instantiated to know which rule to try at the time it is called (that's what the error message means). For instance the queries

```
?- X=member(A,[1,2,3]), X.
```

and

```
?- member(A,[1,2,3]).
```

still allow Prolog to try the definition of the `member` predicate (in fact the two definitions are equivalent) but

```
?- X, X=member(A,[1,2,3]).
```

will throw an exception because at the time `X` should be derived, we don't know that it's supposed to become the predicate `member(A,[1,2,3])`.

Your case is much simpler though: you can wrap `sunny` as a term into a predicate such that Prolog knows which rules to try. The facts

```
weather(sunny).
weather(rainy).
```

define the predicate `weather` such that now we only have a first-order variable as argument in our query:

```
?- weather(X).
X = sunny ;
X = rainy.
```

Now that we are talking about the term level, everything works as you expected.

(*) Although the problem of finding out if a formula is valid is undecidable in both cases, in first order logic at least all true formulas can be eventually derived but if a formula is false, the search might not terminate (i.e. first-order logic is semi-decidable). For second order logic there are formulas that can neither be proved not disproved. What is worse is that we cannot even tell if a second-order formula belongs to this category.

Comment: Got it. All the resolution algorithm descriptions I've read simply say (basically) "go through the list of goals, take each and try to unify it with the head of each rule in the program, recursively. Then compose the MGUs".  "Goal" is defined as a term, and since term is defined as "an atom, variable or compound term (functor)"...you can see how I got here.  X will unify with sunny, therefore I assumed that the answer would be X = sunny. So, I guess they should say that "a goal for resolution must be a non-variable term"? Or is there some other subtlety in the definitions that implies this?

Comment: Prolog blurs the line between the term and formula layers, in particular when it comes to the the meta-logical predicates (certainly not beginner's material :) ). In first order logic, a clause of the form `X` or `X(1,2,3)` is just not allowed by the language and in particular beginners texts just pretend that `X` is not a legal Prolog query at all. Then the unification of the goal with a rule head is always of the form `goal(Something)` and `head(SomethingElse)` and unification always results in a substition of terms.

Comment: If you would allow higher-order unification, just deciding which rules could possibly be applied is only semi-decidable. Unification problems like `X(f(a)) = f(X(a))` have infinitely many most general unifiers (another nice feature of first order logic that's lost when quantifying over formulas / functions). Usually the tree of all possible derivations is finitely branching but might have paths of infinite depth. With higher-order unifiers, the search tree suddenly becomes (possibly) infinitely branching as well.